# Calculating matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to follow the lecture notes for a dynamical systems class, and they say the norm of  $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & -3 \mu x_2^2\\-3 \mu x_1^2 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ is $3 \mu x_1^2 x_2^2$.  How exactly did they compute that?

Thanks!

Comment: We were trying to analyze the structural stability of the differential equation $\dot{x_1} = -x_1 + \mu x_2^3$, $\dot{x_2} = -x_2 + \mu x_1^3$, and to do that we had to find the $C^1$ norm of $f - g$, where $f$ was the vector field where $\mu = 0$ and $g$ was the vector field where $\mu \neq 0$.  So I wanted to find the matrix norm of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (f - g)$

Comment: I suspect the authors made a mistake? It doesn't match any of the usual suspects $\|\cdot \|_\alpha$ with $\alpha \in \{ 1 , 2, \infty, F \}$.

Comment: (Also, the above cannot be correct, as the norm is positive homogeneous, the above would contradict this. Basically the 'units' are wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the authors made a mistake.

All the $p$-norms result in the same induced norm value: $\|A\|_p = \max_{\| y \|_p \le 1} \|A y \|_p = \max_{\| y \|_p \le 1} 3 |\mu|\sqrt[p]{x_1^4 y_1^2+ x_2^4 y_2^2} = 3 |\mu| \max(x_1^2, x_2^2)$.

The Frobenius norm gives $\|A\|_F = 3|\mu|\sqrt{x_1^4 + x_2^4}$.

Comment: i didn't know you could do that

Comment: I goofed, I think. I am checking...

Comment: Why is it the square root of the maximum eigenvalue?

Comment: @badatmath: That's how you compute $\|A\|_2$, however, in this case it doesn't matter, as it can be computed directly, see above.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a misprint. To begin with, if $\mu<0$, $3\mu x_1^2x_2^2$ can be negative, which is an impossible norm value. Even if $\mu>0$, since we can take $x_1=0$ and $x_2\not=0$ as the initial conditions, the initial norm value $3\mu x_1^2x_2^2$ would be zero but the matrix is not. Again, this is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to define a matrix norm but according the result you give, we use, for $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$:
$$||A||=\max_{\lambda\in \mathrm{sp}(A^*A)}(\sqrt{|\lambda|}),$$
where $\mathrm{sp}(A)$ is the spectrum of the matrix $A$.

We have
$$A^*A=\begin{bmatrix}9\mu^2x_2^4 & 0\\ 0 & 9\mu^2x_2^4\end{bmatrix}$$
so

$$||A||=\max(3|\mu| x_1^2,3|\mu| x_2^2).$$

Comment: What is a spectrum?